# AWS TimeStream Java SDK - configure max number of columns

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-timestream

I am using the AWS timestream Java SDK to query timestream table.

My code

```java
String query = """
            SELECT
              Response,
              ResponseSize,
              RequestSize,
              Url,
              StatusCode,
              time AS RequestTime,
              measure_value::bigint AS RequestDuration
            FROM (table name)
            WHERE (clause)
            """;
QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder()
        .queryString(query)
        .build();

var queryResult = timestreamQueryClient.query(queryRequest);

System.out.println(queryResult.rows().size()); // 5000
```

The response contains all of the columns but with 0 rows and says there are more results. In the AWS console query editor, all works fine.

Experimentally I found out that if I select 7 cols max in the select statement it works. I wanted to use `SELECT *` and that's how I found out about it

In the code above if I just add one more col in the select 'TestId' the number of rows becomes 0

```java
String query = """
            SELECT
              TestId,
              Response,
              ResponseSize,
              RequestSize,
              Url,
              StatusCode,
              time AS RequestTime,
              measure_value::bigint AS RequestDuration
            FROM (table name)
            WHERE (clause)
            """;
QueryRequest queryRequest = QueryRequest.builder()
        .queryString(query)
        .build();

var queryResult = timestreamQueryClient.query(queryRequest);

System.out.println(queryResult.rows().size()); // 0 Rows
```

Both request are successful.

So first of all is there a way to set this number somehow in the SDK and secondly is this a bug? I would expect the response to be 400 telling me that max cols are (something) and not an empty row list.

Comment: `if I use 7 cols max` - `is there a way to set this number` - how did you set it? What's the actual problem here? What's the working and incorrect version?

Comment: I've updated my question. In the SELECT statement, if I select 7 or fewer columns it's working just fine. The problem is that I want to select more than 7 columns

Comment: How many columns do you have? Can you please show the 2 requests and (truncated) output for each request?

Comment: I have 9 columns (dimensions) in total. I've updated my question with more details. The rows array is just empty when the selected cols > 7

Comment: Ah OK I understand. Can you try JSON serialising `queryResult` and comparing the output between the 2 other than the obvious row count difference? And just to make sure, can you please try the other column besides `TestId` just to rule out the column being an issue? (I understand it looks fine in the UI but just in case)

Comment: I did what you suggested. It wasn't JSON serializable. But I noticed that the query progress is 67% in the case with all columns and there is a "nextToken". Using the next token I got all of the results. So you get 0 results until the query is 100% complete that is a bit confusing, but it worked.